# Dynamic membership group with memberof issue in Microsoft Entra

Tags: azure-active-directory

We have the following simple query:

```
user.memberof -any (group.objectId -in ['12ad9ebc-01c8-435c-96a5-dc9c16355de1', 'f117bab7-6d3a-42da-ae12-41321a8cad1f', '102be4c1-fbd3-4b02-baef-29ab61777e9e', '5c9ad77f-d616-4885-ab7b-45b28ba417be', 'bb03dfc7-4ef0-4baa-a328-89d2394d6a1f'])
```

And we're getting the following error when validating a user to see if he is part of the group:
[Validation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTV5U.png)

Anyone faced this kind of error? It show the logic behind the memberof statement but doesn't help much in understanding the real problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in the end the rule is working but the test user feature seems to be broken with the use of memberof! Microsoft didn't botter to mention it

Comment: They mention it: "The dynamic group rule builder and validate feature can't be used for memberOf at this time."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/users/groups-dynamic-rule-member-of#preview-limitations